# Scrolling in div stops working after calling jQuery animate height to 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am to expand a div to height of 100%. However the scrolling within the div stops after the jQuery animate function used to do this returns. This is what I have came up with (the solution still does not work) so far, I am not sure if this is the right way to go about this at all or not:

```
('#containerForPopup').on('scroll', (e) => {
  if (doAnimation) {$('#containerForPopup').animate({ height:'100%' }, 200)} else {$('#containerForPopup').stop()}
});
```

Basically, how can I make the #containerForPopup div scrollable again?

Comment: The scrolling in the div stops after what...??

Comment: After $(element).animate() returns

Comment: If that's the case... you'd want to add an end animation listener in which you set the `overflow: auto`

Comment: Can I suggest animating the `max-height` instead of height...

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snipppets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (press the button with `<>` in it or press Ctrl+M). Right now, we don't really have enough information to recreate the issue.

Comment: The height of an element should be smaller than the included content in order to be scrollable.